# Search text and copy another text from file. C#

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to do this I'm trying, I'll explain..
First, Sorry for my english..

I have this:

```
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"myfile.txt");
        WebClient testador = new WebClient();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] campos = line.Split(':');
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
```

I need he get the word of **campos[0]**, ex. campos[0] = apple

and search this word in other file .txt, ex: myfile2.txt, and copy the next 10 letters..

Again, sorry for my english.

EDIT¹:
**First i get the text in myfile.txt, ex: Line 1 of MyFile.txt is: "apple:yeah:test" i use string[] campos = line.Split(':'), to separe, campos[0] = apple, now.. i need to search apple in myfile2.txt, and copy the next 10 letters from it.**

Thanks guys. :D

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to store a collection of strings? How to open other files? How to check whether a line contains a string?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Do you need that just for the first item in ``campos`` or all of them? What if there's more than one occurrence of the word in the other file? Copy the next letters in the other file? To where?

Comment: First i get the text in myfile.txt, ex: Line 1 of MyFile.txt is: "apple:yeah:test" i use string[] campos = line.Split(':'), to separe, campos[0] = apple, now.. i need to search apple in myfile2.txt, and copy the next 10 letters from it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of what you want to do I wrote this code in a way that you can follow step by step. Hopefully it can help you with what you want to do.
To start, just feed it your 2 text files and run it to see if it gives you the results that you want.

```
var file1 = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file1.txt";
var file2 = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file2.txt";

var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(file1);
var file2Text = File.ReadAllText(file2);

var file1WordList = new List<string>();
var file2WordListWithExtraTenLetters = new List<string>();

foreach (var l in file1Lines)
{
    file1WordList.AddRange(l.Split(':'));
}

for (int i = 0; i < file1WordList.Count; i++)
{
    if (file2Text.Contains(file1WordList[i]))
    {
        var indexOfWordFromFile1InFile2 = file2Text.IndexOf(file1WordList[i]);
        file2WordListWithExtraTenLetters.Add(file2Text.Substring(indexOfWordFromFile1InFile2, 10));
    }
}

// Test it
foreach (var element in file1WordList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
Console.WriteLine("=====================");
foreach (var element in file2WordListWithExtraTenLetters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```